# How to use Widget Class with Screen class

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I made a kivy application where everything is done within this class :

class MyGame(Widget):

Consequently, my kv file look like this

```
<MyGame>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                id: question
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: 0.77, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.09, "y":0.85}
                on_press: root.start_round()
            SmoothButton:
```

But now that my game is almost done I feel the need to include 2 screens:

```
One is for the game menu (to let the user select a game mode)
The other one is for the game itself
```

I have tried to include this in my main.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')

class MyGame(Widget):
   ...
```

and my class that inherits from App returns kv in build

Here is my kv file: WindowManager: MenuScreen: GameScreen:

```
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'Menu'
    Button:
<GameScreen>:
    name: 'Game'
    <MyGame>:
```

As you can see I have tried to nest MyGame(Widget) within the GameScreen(Nest) but when I run my code, a screen opens but the screen is black

Does anyone know how I can solve my issue ? This is pretty much my first project in kivy so I have many basics things to learn yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'Menu'
    Button:
<GameScreen>:
    name: 'Game'
    <MyGame>:
```

This syntax is wrong, you don't want the `<>` around `MyGame`. I don't know if this is the cause of your issue.